# How to set a value inside a variable on data() using a function?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm creating a Vue.js component inside a Laravel App.

After I catch the response with an axios request, I can't put a value inside a variable on method data()

Here is the code:

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap')

window.Vue = require('vue')

Vue.component('card', require('./components/card.vue'))


let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
})
```

**card.vue**

```
<script>
module.exports  = {
    props: [
        'name'
    ],
    data: function() {
        return {
            projects: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getProjects() // NOT WORK?
    },
    methods: {
        getProjects: function() {
            axios.get('/api/v1/getProjects').then(function (response) {

                console.log(response.data)
                this.projects = response.data // NOT WORK

            }).catch(function (error) {

                console.log(error)

            }).then(function () {

            })
        },
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: does the `console.log` print something out as expected? If so, try `this.projects.push(....response.data)`

Comment: yep, the console, prints the object as I expect. About the push:
Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `.bind(this)` or replace `function` with `=>`:

```
getProjects: function() {
        axios.get('/api/v1/getProjects').then((response) => {

            console.log(response.data)
            this.projects = response.data // NOT WORK

        }).catch((error) => {

            console.log(error)

        }).then(function () {

        })
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because of using `this` in response callback. You should use an arrow function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) or save the context in separate variable.